# Access KSQL Server from outside of a Docker Container using a different machine (local network)

Tags: python, docker, rest, ksqldb

I have created the following Docker containers to run `zookeeper`, `kafka`, `ksql`, and `ksql-cli` as well. When I am running the command `docker-compose exec ksqldb-cli ksql http://ksqldb-server:8088` from the same machine where Docker is running, `ksql-cli` can access the `ksql-server` just fine.

However, I want to have access to the `ksql-server` outside of the same machine but using a different laptop under the same local network. How do I do that?

Here's the relevant `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    networks:
      - kafka_network
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 22181:2181
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka
    networks:
      - kafka_network
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
      - 29093:29093
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://:29092,EXTERNAL_DIFFERENT_HOST://:29093,INTERNAL://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://localhost:29092,EXTERNAL_DIFFERENT_HOST://192.168.178.218:29093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_DIFFERENT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  ksqldb-server:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:latest
    container_name: ksqldb-server
    hostname: ksqldb-server
    networks:
      - kafka_network
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafka:9092"
      KSQL_HOST_NAME: ksqldb-server
      KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
      KSQL_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING: 0
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'

  ksqldb-cli:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-cli:latest
    container_name: ksqldb-cli
    networks:
      - kafka_network
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - ksqldb-server
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    tty: true
networks:
  kafka_network:
    name: kafka_docker_sse
```

When I try accessing the `ksql-server` from a different laptop that is under the same local network, I get a connection error/connection refused. I tried accessing the `ksqldb-server` using the Python [ksql-python](https://github.com/bryanyang0528/ksql-python) package.

`pip install ksql`

```py
from ksql import KSQLAPI
client = KSQLAPI('http://ksql-server:8088')

# OR
# client = KSQLAPI('http://0.0.0.0:8088')
# client = KSQLAPI('http://192.168.178.218:8088')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(client)
```

I also tried changing the `KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"` under the `ksqldb-server` to `KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://192.168.178.218:8088"` but that doesn't work either.

Any hints would be really helpful as I am currently stuck here for the last two days!

Comment: Should work the same as any other external port forward. Use http://192.168.178.218:8088 in the other computer code and keep the listeners as zeroes

Comment: So, you mean I shall use `KSQLAPI('http://192.168.178.218:8088')` on the other computer through Python script and leave the `KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"` under the `ksqldb-server` Docker container as it is?

Comment: That's what I would try, yes.

Comment: Just to let you know that it's working. What a victory. Thank you 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to keep `KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"`. This binds the container to accept all incoming traffic into port 8088

Then, with `ports` in Compose, the host 8088 traffic is forwarded to the container 8088.

So, for any external client, you need to connect to that hosts LAN / external IP on port 8088. You may need to explicitly allow TCP traffic into that server host's firewall for that port.